# Total download size of TeX Live full installation on Linux 64-bit?

Tags: linux, installation, latex, tex, tex-live

I was installing TeX latest version, but didn't realise the amount of files that were going to be downloaded. According to [this site](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), the total **installation** size is 7GB+. But it doesn't mention the total **Download** size. Does anyone know the total download size of TeX Live full installation on Linux 64-bit? And if it is too large for me, then is there any way to pause installation and resume it later on?

[This](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) is the site from where I am following instructions for installation.

Comment: You can start out with a minimal installation https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397174/minimal-texlive-installation and then add packages as you need them with `tlmgr install packagename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press run `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`  the download size is "3.5Gb" more or less.

Just try it and cancel to double check by yourself and your own distro.

It is difficult to predict bc it requires a huge number of dependencies that you may already have, or not.

### Edit

Although this post answers your question (that is the size of the full version), I recommend installing as Sam Carter says in the comment.

Check on the TeX stack exchange site, where there are several installation procedures.

Minimal installations are normally less than a Gb but aren't very useful imho, and installing with `tlmgr` is sometimes tedious.

Comment: I am not using `apt` for installation. Still I have got an idea of what must be the download size. But it doesn't answer to my second question simply because I am not using `apt`, but following the steps mentioned in the website that I have linked.

Comment: Ok, so I have now cancelled that installation process and am now using `apt` equivalent of puppy-linux (`pkg`) to install. So the question is solved. Thanks!

Comment: @user1234 Don't!

Comment: @user1234 The versions distributed by linux are usually terrible outdated!

Comment: @user1234 Just the other day, there was this poor user stuck with an ancient beamer version because ubuntu still distributes no current version

Comment: @MahNeh A custom filter https://stackexchange.com/filters/305027/sam which can notify me either via rss or mail

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ok, so it was kinda difficult to kill `pkg`, but as I have killed it and following your advice, am now installing minimal TeX. Thanks!!! Now I know what that `--no-interaction` meant.